# Any DrRacket keybinding that uses the shift key to modify a letter key doesn't work

Tags: racket, key-bindings

I have **Enable keybindings in menus** unchecked.

As a modifier, the shift key only seems to work for the arrow keys.

For example, in the default active keybindings, "backward-select" is mapped to (c:s:b), but when I hold down ctrl and shift and press "b", it just inserts "B". The same command is also mapped to (s:left), and that works fine. Keybindings without shift also seem to work.

For non-letter keys, I can get around it by making a custom keybind with the up-shifted symbol; (c:colon) works, while (c:s:semicolon) does not.

Thanks for your help.

**Things I have tried:**

- Making my own keybindings as shown in 3.3.9 
  https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html
- using the Capitalized letter E.g. (c:s:J), changing the order, E.g. (s:c:j)
- pressing the keys in a different order
- Both Ubuntu and Windows
- Upgrading to DrRacket 7.6
- Reinstalling DrRacket
- begging
- pleading

Edits:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQbSl.jpg Here's a screenshot of my active keybindings.

Checking Enable keybindings in menus has the expected behaviour, but the shift shortcuts still don't work.

I did have a custom Windows keymapping on with a program called Sharpkeys, but it didn't change shift and I've since disabled it. Now I'm using a Canadian Multilingual Standard keyboard layout, but the US layout doesn't work either.

Comment: Just getting some info here: Do the keybindings work as expected when "Enable keybindings in menus" are checked? Which keyboard and which keyboard layout (country) is used?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a similar screenshot, showing what appears on your system?

[image]

In DrRacket in the menu "Edit" choose the menu item "Keybindings"
then choose "Show Active ...".